# Changing background-image to sql image

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to set the `background-image: url(--SET THIS--)`, to an sql picture?
I was thinking about somthing like this:

```php
$img = $MysqliHandler->query(SELECT  avatar FROM account WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['name'].'"';
```

And then somehow change the url to: `'.base64_encode( $img[0]['avatar'] ).'`

Right now I just have a simple change avatar function, but I want to save this to a specific `"'.$_SESSION['name'].'"`, so that user always have that avatar, and are able to change it.
Should I use `ajax`, and then link the new image to another php, and run a update image sql function there?

```js
$("#ChangeImg").click(function(e) {
  $("#imageUpload").click();
});

function fasterPreview(uploader) {
  if (uploader.files && uploader.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(uploader.files[0]);
  reader.onloadend = function(){
    document.getElementById("imgDivEdit").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";  
   }
  }
}
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
  fasterPreview(this);
});
```

```css
#imageUpload {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(11, 90, 180, 0.795);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#imgDivEdit {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-image: url("https://www.whatsappprofiledpimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Nice-Whatsapp-DP-Profile-Images-4-300x300.jpg");
  background-position: 5px -5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="imgDivEdit"></div>
  <div id="ChangeImg" class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Change Image</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
```

Comment: "Should I use ajax, and then link the new image to another php, and run a update image sql function there?" Yes, except you want to reload the page after the image was uploaded.

Comment: Okay, i will try to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I use `data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$_SESSION['avatar'].'`, as background, in a separate .php file, and this is ofc. included in my .php file:

```php
#imgDivEdit{
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$_SESSION['avatar'].'");
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then I made a if statement, that updates the sql and then retrieve it and update session.

```php
$URL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isset($_POST['Save']) && !empty($_POST['Save']))
{
    if($_FILES["imageUpload"]["size"]>1010000 || $_FILES["imageUpload"]["size"]==0 )
    {
            echo"<h3 style='color:#db4409'>Failed to upload image.</h3>";
    }
    else{            
            $image=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name']));
            $sql='UPDATE accounts SET avatar = ("'.$image.'") WHERE username ='.$_SESSION['name'].'';
            $query = $MysqliHandler->query($sql);
            $sql='SELECT avatar FROM accounts WHERE username ='.$_SESSION['name'].'';
            $avatar = $MysqliHandler->query($sql);
            $_SESSION['avatar'] = base64_encode( $avatar[0]['avatar'] );
            header("Refresh:0; url=$URL");
            exit();                             
    }
}
```

I made a save option to run all this when a image is uploaded, and showed:

```php
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                           
    <input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="imageUpload" placeholder="Photo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" required="" capture>
    <div id="Change" hidden>
        <input  type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-info Save"/> <p style="font-size:11px;">Max size: 1Mb</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

.js

```js
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
    $("#Change").show();
});
```